# documenting private methods in ruby rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, documentation-generation

I can use rdoc to generate Darkfish documentation for rails code including my private methods, as in

```
rdoc app --all
```

but when I use the built in rake task:

```
bin/rake doc:app
```

it won't accept the "--all" option.

Is there an option for this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to pass the `--all` option to the rake task, a workaround is to add `#:doc:` to your private methods:

```
def some_private_method #:doc:
  ...
end
```